# How to expose different functionality of a single type to different modules?

Tags: swift, module, protocol-oriented

I'm working on a small 2-player card game app for iOS. For now, I've separated this app into 3 modules.

- UI
- Game logic
- Networking

I have two pubic protocols in the networking module:

```
public protocol ConnectionManager {
    init(name: String)
    var peers: Property<[String]> { get }
    func invitePeer(at index: Int)
    func respond(accept: Bool)
    var invitation: Signal<String, NoError> { get }
    var response: Signal<Bool, NoError> { get }
}

public protocol MessageTransmission {
    func send(_ data: Data)
    var data: Signal<Data, NoError> { get }
}
```

and there is actually only one concrete implementation which conforms to both two protocols. Lets' say:

```
class Foo: ConnectionManager, MessageTransmission {
    // ... codes omitted
}
```

The **UI** module receives a name from the user and uses it to initialize a `Foo`. Then it displays the nearby players according to the `peers` property. When a user commits an invitation to start a new game, **UI** module forwards this request to the `ConnectionManager` and the `ConnectionManager` handles those dirty works.

For the **game logic** module, it only cares about message transmission, but the transmission depends on the previous "invite-respond" step because we need a target to exchange message with. (the target related concepts are encapsulated, so the **game logic** only knows there is a thing that it can send message to and receive message from.)

My thought is: once a session is established, i.e., once an invitation is responded with `true`, the **UI** module initializes a game logic thing (maybe an instance of a type `Game`) and passes the `ConnectionManager` (although **UI** module initializes an instance of type `Foo`, it stores that instance as of type `ConnectionManager`) to it. But the problem is, the `ConnectionManager` has nothing to do with `MessageTransmission` when looked from the outside even if they're implemented by a single type internally.

- I can do a force case at either side, but it looks tricky.
- I can combine those two protocols, but then the **UI** module and the **game logic** module interacts with a surplus interface (interface that has more features than needed).

Which path should I take? or is there any better way to do this?

ps: The `Foo` can only be initialized by **UI** module because it's the only one who knows about the `name`. And it's also necessary to pass the same instance to the **game logic** module because there are some internal states (the target related thing) which is modified in the previous interaction with **UI** module and effects the later interaction with **game logic** module. I can't think of another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your explanation you need to pass `MessageTransmition` implementation to game logic but do not want to pass `ConnectionManager`.

As soon as instance of `MessageTransmission` depends on result of invitation (or accepting invite) made by `ConnectionManager` you need to build object conformed to `MessageTransmition` from within `ConnectionManager` and pass to game logic. Yes, that means that you couple these two entities but they will have clean responsibilities in this case.

Consider this kind of protocol:

```
protocol ConnectionManager {
  func respond(accept: Bool) -> Signal<MessageTransmition, Error>
}
```

`respond()` method accepts invitation and builds `MessageTransmission` conforming object on success or returns error if accepting failed or if invitation declined. This object you can pass to game logic.